# DevExpress Many-To-Many Association table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, devexpress, xaf

I posted this question at DevExpress support, nevertheless I know that here I might get answers more quickly, this is a super big issue for me and I have been pulling my hairs for 2 days without any success. Hopefully people here might have experience in this framework.

My problem is related to the **association table** that is created by default when an M-N relation exists between two Business Objects.

> Idea is so:
>
> Lets assume I have these objects  -> UNITS and USERS
>
> **For each USER within a UNIT I need to store a STATUS,**  hence I created a new attribute from SQL , called STATUS_IN_UNIT [image]
>
> The problem arises when I want to **access this property programatically**,
> which of course is impossible since I do not have any object
> associated to this table. Only way is to access it through querying
> database.
>
> What I want to achieve is to show this table as in a ListView inside
> the UNIT DetailView, this is MANDATORY since USERS attached to a UNIT
> must be enabled and disabled. I have seen these threads
>
> https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2334
> https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T500887
>
> but then again I am looking for a more trivial solution to this,
> otherwise it would be really time consuming to create views and
> controllers my self in order to handle it. So my questions are as
> below:
>
> **1. How to create a class that references to THIS table ?
> 2. How to show THIS table inside UNITS DetailView and access its properties from the above table?**

It would be greatly appreciated  if you would answer this question.

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: So if i'm reading your data correctly, you want to display a list of units and the associated users within each unit? For this use case, we almost always use a hierarchical data grid, but this may not work for you. On the business object side of things, I create two classes (for your case, Unit and User) and in the parent class I include a List<ChildObject> for the child items. So in your Unit class, you'll have a: 
    List<User> usersInUnit. This should bind nicely to a hierarchical data grid.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have created a user class and create a collection of Unit in it, and a collection user inside Unit class. In that case, XAF will create an auto-created intermediate table called Users_Units which holds both primary key and you can not add any attributes inside it. If you want to add an attribute(s) or property inside the intermediate class, you should create the class explicitly, so here's the code:

```
public class User : BaseObject
{ //... your code here

    [Association("User-UserUnits")]
    public XPCollection<UserUnit> UserUnits
    {
        get
        {
            return GetCollection<UserUnit>("UserUnits");
        }
    }
}

public class Unit : BaseObject
{ // ... your code here

    [Association("Unit-UserUnits")]
    public XPCollection<UserUnit> UsersUnitss
    {
        get
        {
            return GetCollection<UserUnit>("UserUnits");
        }
    }
}

public class UserUnit : BaseObject
{ 
    User user;
    [Association("User-UserUnits")]
    public User User
    {
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("User", ref user, value);
        }
    }

    Unit unit;
    [Association("Unit-UserUnits")]
    public Unit Unit
    {
        get
        {
            return unit;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("Unit", ref unit, value);
        }
    }

    int status;
    public int Status
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("Status", ref status, value);
        }
    }
}
```

But of course with above code you can not link/unlink each other between User and Unit directly. Instead, you should add the detail record manually as it acts as a normal master-detail or one-to-many entity relationship.